# TYPO3: How to get rendered content when extending sys_file_reference?

Tags: file, typo3

I would like to extend the sys_file_reference table. I added a new inline field to add focus points on the image:

```
$temporaryColumns=[
    'focus_points' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Focus Point',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_MYEXTENSION_domain_model_focuspoint',
            'foreign_field' => 'focus_points',
            'foreign_table_field' => 'focus_point_parent',
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ],
        ],

    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'sys_file_reference',
    $temporaryColumns
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
    'sys_file_reference',
    'imageoverlayPalette',
    '--linebreak--,focus_points'
);
```

The field is showing up and I am able to add multiple focus point elements. However, I am not able to connect the added focus points to its parent sys_file_reference.

I tried to add a DatabaseQueryProcessor to the lib.contentElement:

```
lib.contentElement {
   dataProcessing {
      # extend contentElement with Focus Points
      248572475 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
      248572475{
         as = focusPoints
         table = tx_MYEXTENSION_domain_model_focuspoint
         where.data = field: uid
         where.wrap = focus_points IN (SELECT uid FROM sys_file_reference where uid_foreign = |)
      }
   }
}
```

But this renders all focus points of that content element. So if I have multiple sys_file_reference records with it's own focus points, I only get all focus points and cannot relate to which sys_file_reference it belongs.

How can I render these inline focus points, so that I can access it in the image template and render them?